# How to validate whether a path could be executed using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

The aim is to validate whether a parameter could be executed before passing it to a certain Powershell function to avoid the following error:

```
& : The term 'c:\helloworld' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\functions\function.ps1:67 char:9
+       & $createServiceCommand install $serviceName
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\helloworld:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( get-command helloworld -erroraction silentlycontinue ) {
  "Command was found"
}
else {
  "Command was not found"
}
```

Comment: After changing `helloworld` to a commandPath e.g. `C:\Chocolatey\lib\chocolatey.0.9.8.24\tools\chocolateyInstall\NuGet.exe` executing this script results in `Command was found`. Running this script as is results in `Command was not found`. This answers the question. Thank you. I will accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Test-Path cmdlet to check for the existence of the path.

Comment: `Test-Path C:\temp` results in `true` and indicates that the path exist, but it does not indicate whether it could be executed or not.

Comment: Based on the error message you were getting , it implies that path doesn't exist, hence my answer.