# How to validate using Powershell if a command including options could be run?

Tags: powershell

Follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587184/how-to-validate-whether-a-path-could-be-executed-using-powershell).

Executing

```
if ( get-command java -erroraction silentlycontinue ) {
  "Command was found"
}
else {
  "Command was not found"
}
```

results in `Command was found`, while running

```
if ( get-command "java -version" -erroraction silentlycontinue ) {
  "Command was found"
}
else {
  "Command was not found"
}
```

returns `Command was not found`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-Command` looks for commands (that is, executable programs, cmdlets, functions, aliases to those things, etc.), not things that would constitute a valid command line to execute. If you want that, you just need to try executing it:

```
try {
  $javaVersion = java -version
  Write-Host Java found with version $javaVersion
} catch {
  Write-Host Command was not found
}
```

Of course, care should be taken that whatever you try executing there doesn't do anything you might regret.

Comment: This answers the question. Thank you.